# Inheriting ThreadStatic values to implement dynamic scoping in C#/.NET in multithreaded context

Tags: c#, logging, scope, threadstatic

Is there a way to make newly-spawned threads inherit the values of ThreadStatic state (or something like it) on their parent threads?  I would like to use this (or something like it) to implement "dynamically scoped" special variables that contain operation/task context information to use for tracking/logging, etc.  Is this a reasonable approach, and can it be made to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't "inherit" values.  However, the new [`ThreadLocal<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(VS.100).aspx) for .NET 4 allows you to provide a `Func<T>` in the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642263(VS.100).aspx), which can initialize the thread based on the parent's state.  This would provide a reasonable workaround.

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly interesting.  But how would I allow the child to access the parent's state?

Comment: You could use a lambda in the parent that provides access to the variable(s) in question that are required to initalize the ThreadLocal<T>.  This uses a form of lazy initialization, so on first use, you'd get the current parent's state.

Comment: this didn't do what I needed at the time for some reason I've forgotten, but it was nice to know about this anyway.